# VirtualBox Moving the Mini Toolbar

Tags: virtualbox, xfce

In VirtualBox, I'm running 6.0.16, I can see you can move the mini toolbar to the top of the screen, but I am running XFCE in the guest OS which means the mini toolbar will go over the opened item tabs

Is there a way to move the mini toolbar like you can move the MS RDP toobar around the edges of the screen?

The bottom gets in my way, the top gets in my way, but if I could offset it to the left or right of the top/bottom that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite annoying where this setting is. When "Show at top. . " is unchecked it goes to the bottom.

[image]